# javascript popup routes to wrong URI [rails]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I have a link_to that creates a popup. It works on some pages but when I click it on other pages it goes to the wrong URI. Is the issue with my app architecture? I want all links to route to

```
http://localhost:3000/microposts/361/into_it.
```

SHARED/_feed_item.html.erb---This line of code routes properly:

```
<%= link_to "#{feed_item.votes_for} Into it!", into_it_micropost_path(feed_item.id), :onclick => "javascript:window.open('microposts/#{feed_item.id}/into_it','popup','width=350,height=300,top=315,left=200');", id: "feeditemlikes_#{feed_item.id}", remote: true %>
```

USERS/_vote_feed_item.html.erb---
On the like page it routes to

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/microposts/361/into_it

<%= link_to "#{vote_feed_item.votes_for} Into it!", into_it_micropost_path(vote_feed_item.id), :onclick => "javascript:window.open('microposts/#{vote_feed_item.id}/into_it','popup','width=350,height=300,top=315,left=200');", id: "feeditemlikes_#{vote_feed_item.id}", remote: true %>
```

MICROPOSTS/_micropost.html.erb---On the profile page it routes to

```
http://localhost:3000/users/microposts/361/into_it

<%= link_to "#{micropost.votes_for} Into it!", into_it_micropost_path(micropost.id), :onclick => "javascript:window.open('microposts/#{micropost.id}/into_it','popup','width=350,height=300,top=315,left=200');", id: "feeditemlikes_#{micropost.id}", remote: true %>
```

Actually it seems the problem is with the javascript popup code, any hints?

Comment: Do you need the 'remote: true'?

Comment: I need it so the page doesn't refresh/change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you always want to link to `http://localhost:3000/microposts/361/into_it`

Then you should prepend your paths with a leading slash:

```
"javascript:window.open('/microposts/#{micropost.id}/into_it', ..."
```

Or better, use the rails path helper, something like this:

```
"javascript:window.open(#{into_it_path(micropost)}, ..."
```